# What is the tortoisehg gui equivalent of doing "hg push -r"

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I don't see the options to accomplish this.  I want to only push changesets related to my default branch, not any other local branches I have.

I thought I could do this by using the Repository Explorer like so: On the toolbar below the repository address, the first combo box allows me to select a branch. I set this to default. However once I push outgoing, it wants to flag local changesets not in default.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aufter you determine the outgoing revisions with the green up-arrow, the "Push to Here" options appears in the context-menu of a selected revision.

"Push to Here" is the equivalent of "push -r"

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You now directly have a "Push selected branch" option.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure out @J.Graumann's answer above hence this answer for those who like pictures:

1. In TortoiseHg click on `Detect outgoing changes to` button.
   [image]
2. Click right mouse button on revision you want to push.
3. Choose `Push -> Push to Here`.
   [image]

Result: You will push only revision selected rather than everything.
[image]

Hope this saves you some time.